# Test for a specific character with a .txt file (Applescript)

Tags: macos, applescript

Hi Applescript Stackoverflow Community!

I am attempting to write a code in which a different action will occur depending on the 1st character of a .txt file. This is my code so far (I'm fairly new to Applescript so I'm sorry if this is a basic question).

```
if first character of "/Users/Goombado/Documents/applescript_test.txt" is 1 then
    display dialog "Hi"
else
    display dialog "Hello"
    end tell
end if
```

Is it possible to do this in Applescript or not?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not so far.

1) instruction "end tell" should always be after a "tell application" instruction. But in this case, there is no need to call any application.

2) you need to tell the script to read the text file, and the file paths in script are using ":". You can use also paths with "/" separator, but then via posix conversion.

```
set C1 to first character of (read file "Users:Goombado:Documents:applescript_test.txt")
if C1 = "1" then
    display dialog "Hi"
else
    display dialog "Hello"
end if
```

Note : You should avoid to hardcode path and file name.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick reply! I'll keep that in mind :)